# Row space subsets in matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> If I have 2 matrices,
>
> $A, B$ and suppose the product $AB$ exists, what can you say about $\text{row } AB, \text{row } A, \text{row } B$?

I've seen that people claim $\text{row }AB \subseteq \text{row } B$,

But I don't see intuition or any thought as to how this works?

**One way to prove?**

$\text{row } AB = \{B^TA^Tx | x \in \mathbb{R}^m \}$

$\text{row }B = \{B^Tx|x \in \mathbb{R}^m \}$

Let $y \in \text{row } AB$, then $y = B^TA^T x = B^T(A^T x) \in \text{row } B$?

Does this work? I am not sure about the dimensions of $A^Tx$, so I am in second thoughts?

Comment: I think that's wrong. The row space of $AB$ is contained in the row space of $B$, not $A$.

Comment: @user49640, updated the Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that for any matrix $X$,
$$
\operatorname{row}X=\operatorname{col}X^{\intercal}=\operatorname{range}X^{\intercal}.
$$
Moreover, for any two compatible matrices $X$ and $Y$,
$$
\operatorname{range}(XY)\subset\operatorname{range}X
$$
What can you conclude from these facts?

Comment: I made an edit using the definition, can you help confirm that? (+1)

Comment: @Amad27: Yes, it looks good

Answer (score 1):

The row space of $A$ consists of all products $X^T A$, where $X^T$ can be any row matrix.

Now if you take any element $Y^T$ of the row space of $AB$, it can be written as $Y^T = X^T (AB)$ for some row matrix $X^T$. But then $Y^T = (X^T A)B$, which shows that $Y^T$ can be written as the product of a row matrix and $B$. Therefore it belongs to the row space of $B$.

Thus the row space of $AB$ is contained in the row space of $B$.